# ORACLE ADD days into Column Using Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help with assignment question! Need to use update with a sub-query to add correct days into different rows who match with proper column and row from other table. Trying to update the due date (7 days + checkedOut date) of entries with DVD only. SO far i tried using following code

```
UPDATE LOAN 
SET (SELECT DUEDATE 
     FROM Media 
     JOIN Item USING (MediaID)  
     JOIN  InventoryItem USING (ItemID) 
     JOIN Loan USING (InventoryItemID) 
     WHERE MediaCode = 'DVD')  =  DATETIME (checkedOut, '+7 days')
```

For some reasons it keep giving me error "near "(": syntax error: " when trying to run it. Simply I want to change all the due dates of DVD's to add correctly (7 days) according to checkedout date. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's Oracle.I tried using SET table = value but it keeps changing all the duedates rather than just one category i.e. DVD.

Comment: Please change the tag  to oracle.  imo,  it doesn't really change much as you use a subquery and you do not tell SQL which column to store the result into? Which column in `LOAN` do you actually want to update? change the the query to be something like: `Update loan SET  loan.columnA = (subquery) where loan.columnA = 42;`  for example

Comment: It would help if you provided the structure of the involved tables, at least the tables and their relative columns. Including a sample of the data in each of those tables would also be helpful, but not really necessary. The main thing is to know how your tables are structured and which field you actually want updated.

Comment: At last i made it working thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE LOAN 
SET   DUEDATE =  checkedOut + INTERVAL '7' DAY
WHERE InventoryItemID IN (
  SELECT InventoryItemID
  FROM   InventoryItem
         JOIN Item  USING ( ItemID )
         JOIN Media USING ( MediaID )
  WHERE  MediaCode = 'DVD'
)
```